# Oracle - Select Only Columns That Contain Data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a database with a vast number of tables and columns that was set up by a 3rd party.

Many of these columns are entirely unused.  I am trying to create a query that returns a list of all the columns that are actually used (contain > 0 values).

My current attempt -

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE OWNER = 'XUSER' 
    AND num_nulls < 1
;
```

Using `num_nulls < 1` dramatically reduces the number of returned values, as expected.

However, on inspection of some of the tables, there are columns missing from the results of the query that appear to have values in them.

Could anybody explain why this might be the case?

Comment: These columns are set when statistics are gathered. Try running gather stats using analyze statement or dbms_stats package

Answer (score 1):

First of all, statistics are not always 100% accurate.  They can be gathered on a subset of the table rows, since they are, after all, *statistics*.  Just like pollsters do not have to ask every American how they feel about a given politician, Oracle can get an accurate-enough sense of the data in a table by reading only a portion of it.

Even if the statistics were gathered on 100% of the rows in a table (and they *can* be gathered that way, if you want), the statistics will become outdated as soon as there are any inserts, updates, or deletes on the table.

Second of all, `num_nulls < 1` wouldn't tell you the columns that had no data.  Imagine a table with 100 rows and "column X" having `num_nulls` equal to 80.  That would imply the column has 20 non-null values, but would NOT pass your filter.  A better approach (if you trust your statistics are not stale and based on a 100% sample of the rows), might be to compare `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.NUM_NULLS < DBA_TABLES.NUM_ROWS`.  For example, a column that has 99 nulls in a 100 row table has data in 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

> "there are columns missing from the results of the query that appear to have values in them."

Potentially every non-mandatory column could appear in this set, because it is likely that some rows will have values but not all rows. "Some rows" being greater than zero means such columns won't pass your test for `num_nulls < 1`.

So maybe you should search for columns which aren't in use. This query will find columns where every row is null:

```
 select t.table_name
        , tc.column_name
 from user_tables t
      join user_tab_cols tc on t.table_name = tc.table_name
 where t.num_rows > 0
and  t.num_rows = tc.num_nulls;
```

Note that if you are using Partitioning you will need to scan `user_tab_partitions.num_rows` and `user_part_col_statistics.num_nulls`.

Also, I second the advice others have given regarding statistics. The above query may throw out some false positives. I would treat the results generated from that query as a list of candidates to be investigated further. For instance you could generate queries which counted the actual number of nulls for each column.